# Anonymous function in setInterval function javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following tags in my html documentation:

```
<p id="demo1">This is my animation text</p>
<button onclick="runAnimation()">RunAnimation</button>
```

I have declared the following javascript code to make animation for the text in

tag:

```
function changeText(){
    var text = document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML;
    text = text.substr(text.length - 1) + text.substr(0, text.length - 1);
    document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = text;
}

`function` runAnimation(){
    setInterval(changeText(), 300);
}
```

The code above didn't work, instead, when i use anonymous function, everything now OK, can anyone explain me why?

```
function runAnimation(){
    setInterval(function(){
        var text = document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML;
        text = text.substr(text.length - 1) + text.substr(0, text.length - 1);
        document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = text;
    }, 300);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass the function itself to `setInterval`, e.g.:

```
setInterval(changeText, 300);
```

Instead, you've coded:

```
setInterval(changeText(), 300);
```

This calls `changeText` and passes the returned value (in this case, `undefined`) to `setInterval`.